# How do I split an integer using an "if" condition?

Tags: regex, if-statement, awk, sed, string-length

I've been looking for days trying to use awk, sed, cut, and tr for a possible solution to my problem. I have a data set thats delimited with a "@" as shown below...

```
1@2@11@11/8@11/8@11@11/2
2@4@31 1/2@31 1/2@31/2@21@21/2
3@10@116 1/4@98@911 3/4@410@38 1/2
4@1@21@21/8@21/8@33@49 1/4
5@11@74@75@67 1/2@511 1/2@511 1/2
6@9@106@108 1/4@89 1/4@613 1/2@616
7@7@96@118 1/4@1313 1/2@715@717 3/4
8@12@127 3/4@129 3/4@1212 1/2@816 1/2@817 3/4
9@6@63@ 64 1/2@79@916 1/2@918
10@13@139 3/4@1311 1/4@1112@1017@1019 3/4
11@3@42@42@43 1/2@1118 1/2@1126 1/4
12@5@84 1/2@87@1011 3/4@1219 1/2@1228 1/4
13@8@52 1/2@53 1/2@57@1324@1332 3/4
```

What I would like to do is split the row numbers in the first column (the ranks) from the rest of the integers in the other columns starting at column 3 and on. The end results would look like this...

```
1@2@1@1@1@1/8@1@1/8@1@1@1@1/2
2@4@3@1 1/2@3@1 1/2@3@1/2@2@1@2@1/2
3@10@11@6 1/4@9@8@9@11 3/4@4@10@3@8 1/2
4@1@2@1@2@1/8@2@1/8@3@3@4@9 1/4
5@11@7@4@7@5@6@7 1/2@5@11 1/2@5@11 1/2
6@9@10@6@10@8 1/4@8@9 1/4@6@13 1/2@6@16
7@7@9@6@11@8 1/4@13@13 1/2@7@15@7@17 3/4
8@12@12@7 3/4@12@9 3/4@12@12 1/2@8@16 1/2@8@17 3/4
9@6@6@3@6@4 1/2@7@9@9@16 1/2@9@18
10@13@13@9 3/4@13@11 1/4@11@12@10@17@10@19 3/4
11@3@4@2@4@2@4@3 1/2@11@18 1/2@11@26 1/4
12@5@8@4 1/2@8@7@10@11 3/4@12@19 1/2@12@28 1/4
13@8@5@2 1/2@5@3 1/2@5@7@13@24@13@32 3/4
```

I was thinking that I could use an "if statement".  Something like "if integers start with [2-9] then split after one character, elif it starts with [1] and length is equal to 3 or more (before the space and fraction) then split the firsts two characters."  I have no idea how to how to go about solving this problem.  I have thousands of similar files and need to change the structure for all of them, so the solution will have to be ran through a loop.

Comment: You're throwing too much data. Please show 4 or 5 numbers, and then how they should be split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fun one:

```
perl -F@ -lape '$_ = join "@", shift(@F), shift(@F), map {s/(1\d|\d)(\d+)/$1\@$2/g; $_} @F' file
```

With a little commentary

```
perl -F@ -lape '
    $_ = join "@",                # join the following things, using "@" 
              shift(@F),          #   the first field
              shift(@F),          #   the second field
              map {               #   then, transform the rest with this expr
                  s{              #     search for:
                      (1\d | \d)  #       1 plus a digit, or a digit
                      (\d+)       #       followed by one or more digits
                   }{$1\@$2}xg;   #     add an "@" in between
                  $_              #     and return the new string
              } @F
' file
```

The options:

- `-a` and `-F@` -- split each line into the array `@F` using the `@` character as the separator
- `-l` -- handle line endings automatically
- `-p` -- automatically print the variable `$_` after processing each line

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty much a transcription of the logic as you described it in awk (I added the assumption that starting with 1 and having length 2 should split after the first character). I also noticed in row 9 there was a space after the @ delimiter, so added that possibility to the field separator as you can see in the `BEGIN` block --- maybe with the real data you don't need that, so just to be aware. I did in the end get your expected output, but probably you want to desk-check this on larger data sets in case there are some more use cases not taken into account.

```
$ cat jd.awk
BEGIN { FS = " *@ *"; OFS = "@" }

{
    for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) {
        # if integers start with [2-9] then split after one character
        if (substr($i, 1, 1) ~ /[2-9]/) {
            $i = substr($i, 1, 1) "@" substr($i, 2)
        }
        else {
            split($i, parts, "[ /]")

            # else if it starts with [1] and length is equal to 2
            # (before the space and fraction) then split the first character
            if (substr($i, 1, 1) == "1" && length(parts[1]) == 2) {
                $i = substr($i, 1, 1) "@" substr($i, 2)
            }

            # else if it starts with [1] and length is equal to 3 or more
            # (before the space and fraction) then split the firsts two characters.
            else if (substr($i, 1, 1) == "1" && length(parts[1]) >= 3) {
                $i = substr($i, 1, 2) "@" substr($i, 3)
            }
        }
    }
    print
}

$ cat jd.txt
1@2@11@11/8@11/8@11@11/2
2@4@31 1/2@31 1/2@31/2@21@21/2
3@10@116 1/4@98@911 3/4@410@38 1/2
4@1@21@21/8@21/8@33@49 1/4
5@11@74@75@67 1/2@511 1/2@511 1/2
6@9@106@108 1/4@89 1/4@613 1/2@616
7@7@96@118 1/4@1313 1/2@715@717 3/4
8@12@127 3/4@129 3/4@1212 1/2@816 1/2@817 3/4
9@6@63@ 64 1/2@79@916 1/2@918
10@13@139 3/4@1311 1/4@1112@1017@1019 3/4
11@3@42@42@43 1/2@1118 1/2@1126 1/4
12@5@84 1/2@87@1011 3/4@1219 1/2@1228 1/4
13@8@52 1/2@53 1/2@57@1324@1332 3/4


$ awk -f jd.awk jd.txt 
1@2@1@1@1@1/8@1@1/8@1@1@1@1/2
2@4@3@1 1/2@3@1 1/2@3@1/2@2@1@2@1/2
3@10@11@6 1/4@9@8@9@11 3/4@4@10@3@8 1/2
4@1@2@1@2@1/8@2@1/8@3@3@4@9 1/4
5@11@7@4@7@5@6@7 1/2@5@11 1/2@5@11 1/2
6@9@10@6@10@8 1/4@8@9 1/4@6@13 1/2@6@16
7@7@9@6@11@8 1/4@13@13 1/2@7@15@7@17 3/4
8@12@12@7 3/4@12@9 3/4@12@12 1/2@8@16 1/2@8@17 3/4
9@6@6@3@6@4 1/2@7@9@9@16 1/2@9@18
10@13@13@9 3/4@13@11 1/4@11@12@10@17@10@19 3/4
11@3@4@2@4@2@4@3 1/2@11@18 1/2@11@26 1/4
12@5@8@4 1/2@8@7@10@11 3/4@12@19 1/2@12@28 1/4
13@8@5@2 1/2@5@3 1/2@5@7@13@24@13@32 3/4
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^@]*@){2})/\1\n/;ta;:a;/\n[0-9]?$/s/\n//;t;/\n(1[0-9]|[0-9])([0-9][0-9]?)/s//\1@\2\n/;ta;/\n([0-9]?[^0-9\n]) ?/s//\1\n/;ta' file
```

This inserts a newline following the second field and then pattern matches and loops, each successive match moves the newline forward until the end of the line when the newline is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your quick responses.
They helped me with the parsing of my data sets that needed to be done before an upload.  The solution that I ended up using was the one based on pearl due to simplicity.
Again, Thank You for your answers.